Postgresql DB in Next.js WebApp ~ Requests take too much time
I'm currently trying to make a webapp using Vercel's postgresql data storage. However when I'm fetching my database since my backend the request takes too much time.
When I use the vercel tools in the data base directly, it's working properly : 
Whereas, when I have fetched the DB since my Express Backend the request takes an infinite amount of time...
router.get("/randomcard", async function (req, res, next) {
  const client = await db.connect();
  let data = await client.sql`SELECT * FROM Cards
  ORDER BY RANDOM()
  LIMIT 1;`;
  console.log("Card selected from db : " + data.name);
  res.set("Cache-Control", "no-store");
  res.json(data);
  await client.end();
});

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong, so I hope someone will explain to me the issue ^^ Thanks.

If it took an infinite amount of time you would still be waiting while you typed in this question.

I'm currently still waiting...

ORDER BY random() doesn't help, especially on very large tables. For a 100 records you wouldn't notice it. Also check table locks from other processes

Yea instead of ORDER BY RANDOM() you could get the whole result set and then pick a random single element

Kk I will try, but I still  dont understand the difference between my backend request and the vercel tool query
